# Listview to retrieve the data from other file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve the data in listview from below path instead of same file. Can you please advise as to what all changes are required in my code.

```
myFileNameDir = "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Book16.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students")

'Code for retrieving data from same file.

Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim LstItem As ListItem
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set rngData = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For Each rngCell In rngData.Rows(1).Cells
        Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=rngCell.Value, Width:=90
    Next rngCell

RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count

ColCount = rngData.Columns.Count

    For i = 2 To RowCount
        Set LstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add(Text:=rngData(i, 1).Value)
        For j = 2 To ColCount
            LstItem.ListSubItems.Add Text:=rngData(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the data to the ListView from the rngData Range, and here is where you set up that Range:

```
    Set rngData = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

If you want to use the data from the workbook that you opened, you should modify rngData to refer to that workbook instead:

```
    Set rngData = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```